# Запуск Activity из Application

Tags: android

Мне нужно запускать определенную Activity из Application (в зависимости от настроек). Собственно активити и запускается.. но также запускается и та активити, которая прописана в манифесте. Т.е. в стеке оказываются 2 активити. Из манифеста убрать LAUNCHER-активити нельзя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Цель:** Если пользовать вошел в аккаунт, то запускаем главную активность приложения, иначе - активность входа:

**Способ 1**

Cоздаем дополнительную активность, которая будет входной точкой приложения и в ней уже запускаем нужную активность.

```
public class LauncherActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Class target;
        if (Prefs.getInstance().isLoggedIn()) {
            target = MainActivity.class;
        } else {
            target = LoginActivity.class;   
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, target);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Зарегистрируйте ее в манифесте как `LAUNCHER` а у остальных его уберите

**Способ 2**

Оставляем MainActivity точкой входа и проверяем вошел ли пользователь, если нет - кидаем его на LoginActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(!Prefs.getInstance().isLoggedIn()) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
            finish(); //обязательно
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // ... остальной код
```

**Способ 3.**

Собственно, наоборот. Делаем LoginActivity входной точкой, если пользователь вошел - запускаем главную.

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if(Prefs.getInstance().isLoggedIn()) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                finish(); //обязательно
            }
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
            // ... остальной код
```

**Способ 4 (bad practice, ненадежный)**

Оставляем `MainActivity` точкой входа, но в `Application` проверяем, если пользовать не вошел, то кидаем его на `LoginActivity` (можно наоборот)

```
public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if(!Prefs.getInstance().isLoggedIn()){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // этот флаг очистит стек активностей при переходе
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Я рекомендую использовать все-таки первый вариант, так как он логичнее, активность выполняет роль разветвления. Если логика усложняется, то второй/третий вариант станет обузой, которая будет мозолить глаза.

Предлагайте свои варианты решения ))

Comment: Ну это как-бы очевидное решение. Просто не хотел лишнюю активити вводить, которая нужна только для запуска других.

Comment: К сожалению, другие способы невозможны, потому что андроиду обязательно нужна лаунчер активити

Comment: @Рома, дополнил ответ